# Triggers in MySQL not being triggered

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I've been able to create these trigger in mysql database:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgv_customer_insert AFTER INSERT on tgv_customer 
for each row   
insert into salesforce_event_history(flow_name,fk_oid,last_mod_time) values 
            ('CustomerOrProspect1',NEW.id_customer,sysdate());

CREATE TRIGGER tgv_customer_update AFTER UPDATE on tgv_customer 
for each row   
insert into salesforce_event_history(flow_name,fk_oid,last_mod_time) values 
           ('CustomerOrProspect2',NEW.id_customer,sysdate());
```

However it seems they're not triggered...
Do you have an idea why ?

show triggers; -- => 2 triggers created on tgv_customer table
select id_customer, last_login from tgv_customer where last_login is not null order by last_login desc limit 5; -- => I checked tgv_customer was updated very recently
select * from salesforce_event_history; -- => empty table, so no trigger was triggered

**I added the info to the dbfiddle link**
thanks

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/-TgYktcd

Comment: so, the triggers are all right? It does not work in production. Perhaps a permissions issue for the user who created the triggers?

Comment: 'I added the info to the dbfiddle link thanks' - don't - add it to the question.

Comment: thanks to both. Still not sure why is it not working for me in production. But seems it should based on this test in dbfiddle